# Why are face covering ban policies being proposed?

Tags: policy, europe

There have been plenty of instances in recent history across Europe where parties want to ban covering of the face:

- [Norway Proposes Ban on Face Covering in Schools, Kindergartens](http://uk.businessinsider.com/r-norway-proposes-ban-on-full-face-veils-in-schools-2017-6?r=US&IR=T)
- [Ukip pledge to ban the burqa in party manifesto](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/ukip-ban-muslim-burqa-sharia-law-postal-voting-paul-nuttall-a7697426.html) - [UK General Election]
- [French Ban on face covering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_ban_on_face_covering)
- [German parliament votes in favour of partial burqa ban](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/germany-burqa-ban-law-vote-favour-angela-merkel-islam-muslim-civil-servants-judges-military-a7706781.html)
- [European Parliament’s biggest political group calls for EU-wide ban on Islamic face veils](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/islamic-veil-burka-ban-face-european-peoples-party-manfred-weber-a7672606.html)

to name a few...

---

What reasons could parties have to be proposing face covering bans?

Comment: Comments deleted. Please don't use comments to answer the question. Also don't use comments to soap-box your personal opinions about the subject of this question. Question comments are only meant to ask for clarification or provide constructive criticism on the question itself.

Comment: Don't forget Turkey!

Comment: This is rather broad, isn't it?  I mean, there are at least two axii (axes) of differences in your examples:  all face coverings i.e. masks, or only veils and burqa components; proposals limited to schools — vis–à–vis attire and degrees of uniformity in government institutions; proposals applicable in all public places.

Comment: The obvious reason not mentioned: security (concealment of any or all of identity, bombs, weapons). But any law imposed for security reasons would have to apply equally to all sorts of full face coverings, not just one kind.

Comment: 2017: ban on face coverings. 2020: ban on not having a face covering :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are three interlocking reasons:

1. Face coverings are perceived as an affront to feminism/women's liberation/etc...

   The fact that women (but not men) are forced to cover their face, is pretty much as naked patriarchal/opposed to feminism as you can get (heck, even most anti-third-wave-feminists agree that it's a valid reason to pro-feminism-protest and is clear inequality). If you recall, in 1960s, feminists vehemently protested *[bras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss_America_protest#Origin_of_.22bra-burning.22)*, and in 1990s, some protested *nipple pasties*. There are worldwide "[slut walks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SlutWalk)", whose main philosophy is feminism-based opposition to the idea that a woman should dress less provocatively to avoid sexual assault.

   Muslim face covering flies/spits in the face of all that (no pun intended).
2. It's viewed by Westerners<sup>[1]</sup> that face coverings are symptomatic and/or symbolic of conservative/radical Islam's treatment of women.

   <sup>[1] - I won't discuss whether this view is correct or not - the complexities of Arab/Middle-Eastern/Central-Asian tribalism and ethnography as intertwined with Islam are way outside the scope of the question. It's enough for explaining the OP's question that the view **is** held, widely.</sup>
3. For those who generally oppose radical Islam, this is viewed as both practical pushback (If you ban face coverings, conservative/radical Muslims wouldn't want to live in that society); as well as symbolic pushback (inasmuch as, per above point, face coverings are seen by many as a symbol of Islam).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60365/discussion-on-answer-by-user4012-why-are-face-covering-policies-still-being-prop).

Comment: There is still a gain to be made by referencing other locales that have issued regulations regarding face coverings. Some include caveats for religious practices: http://www.anapsid.org/cnd/mcs/maskcodes.html

Comment: To clarify, most Muslims, in terms of population, consider the face veil to be *optional*, and forcing it upon someone is considered extreme. In the West, it's almost always the woman opting to wear it.

There is no actual evidence supporting the fact that women who wear the veil in the  West are forced to do so. "Outsiders" just assume it, based on hearsay

Comment: I can't tell if that's what point 3 is about but otherwise plain old racism is missing.

Comment: @Al-Muhandis, In the west, gays are accepted by an overwhelming majority, but even that doesn't necessarily shield some from the violence done to them by their own family members or by their peers for being gay. And even in the west, there can be muslim related honor killings.  There can be plenty of evidence found about that. Also, a survey conducted in France in May 2003 found that 77 percent of girls wearing the hijab said they did so because of physical threats.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Have a source for that survey?

Comment: @Relaxed, Actually, this supposed French study was only quoted in English publications, not French publications, and in hindsight, I think this study was made up I am embarrassed to say. See below: http://blogs.reuters.com/faithworld/2010/03/02/opinion-why-france-is-right-about-the-burqa/ In hindsight, I think that many of the girls who wear the hijab/burqa, simply do it because their parents got them started at a very young age (much younger than puberty).  Others do it because they believe that they're more religious than their Muslim parents (and they're rebelling against them).

Comment: Others do it only because they don't like that the French government is telling them not to. Others still do it because they're experimenting with their identity, or are on a spiritual journey. And don't get me wrong. There is still some sporadic evidence that some do it in France because they're forced by their family, but I believe those only represent a tiny minority (unless we're willing to include those forced to wear it at a very early age so that it becomes second-nature to them).  See link: http://www.sunnisme.com/les-parents-peuvent-ils-forcer-leur-fille-a-porter-le-voile-hijab.html/

Answer (score 28):

In addition to [user4012](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/115/user4012)'s excellent answer it is worth noting that often security, is given as a concern in regards to the full face veil. As [this](http://www.newsweek.com/burqa-ban-european-peoples-party-france-582312) article states :

> Concerns are raised, for example, about the ability of the police or courts to identify and question suspects or witnesses [who are wearing full face coverings].

Comment: Of course, that only applies to prohibitions that stipulate all methods of obscuring the face, and not those which are limited to certain forms — unless, that is, that the drafters of the legal prohibitions are placing apparently Muslim folks under more scrutiny than others.  Is that what you are supposing?  Seems at least somewhat probable.

Comment: @can-ned_food I am not supposing anything, I'm simply outlining that this is an argument used by proponents of bans on a full face veil

Comment: @can-ned_food Most people aren't covering their faces with other methods and are happy to remove them if they are. Banks don't allow you to wear motorcycle helmets, nor could you wear one to court, but if you could refuse to remove it based on anti-religious-discrimination laws then further legal methods to require it be removed under certain circumstances would be necessary.

Comment: Anecdotally, I have heard daycare workers are concerned if they can't verify who is picking up a given child while wearing a burqa. (Logically, this of course wouldn't justify a burqa ban, just a requirement by the daycare that customers need to remove the veil when picking up children.)

Comment: I'd support a ban on security grounds, of any form of full-face covering or mask in a public place except where it was required or permitted by law (e.g. motorcycle helmets while riding, welders' masks while working, bandages on wounds). I'd vehemently oppose any legislation which attempted to single out a particular form of female attire as separate from balaclavas, Fawkes masks, etc. Either we're all equal under the law, or nobody is.

Comment: In some european countries, gathering in public with face obscuring clothing is illegal... And some businesses do have objections to you entering with such clothing on (eg if you enter a bank with a motorcycle helmet or balaclava, this will probably not be taken lightly even if there is not intent at robbery).

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa: But how does viewing a face add all that much to verifying identity?  If there is a real concern, use something like a password or fingerprint scanner.

Comment: @jamesqf Proponents of this idea believe it would be difficult to identify an individual on a CCTV or in a courtroom if their face was not visible

Comment: @nigel222: But I note that some European countries seem to have no problem with banning Nazi regalia, for instance.  Even where it's not illegal, it generally raises a lot of public outcry (e.g. one of the English princes going to a costume party in an SS uniform a few years ago).  The same would be true for people wearing KKK regalia in a lot of the US.

Comment: In the UK there is a crime "behaviour likely to cause a breach of the peace". It's grounds for arresting a person being gratuitously offensive or provocative (to prevent or end the breach of the peace). It may lead to a police caution or an appearance before the magistrates. No list of offensive acts is needed. It's context and intent that are judged.

Comment: @jamesqf `how does viewing a face add all that much to verifying identity?` Surely you're joking? You can steal my password then cover your face and use it too. If you're clever you can do the same with fingerprints. If you can't cover your face, are you going to get plastic surgery to look like me?

Comment: @MrLore: Perhaps I can't look like you (though I might), but faces in general are far from unique, so it would be fairly easy in any large city to find someone who looks sufficiently like you.  (Think for instance of the dozens if not hundreds of indistinguishable blonde Hollywood starlets gracing the covers of magazines in supermarket checkout lines.)  However, I was thinking from the POV of the daycare worker who is hardly going to memorize the face of every parent.

Comment: I think these comments are digressing a bit off topic.  Whether prohibition of identity concealment is ethical in various venues was not the purpose of this answer; my minor complaint was that the answer seemed incomplete:  it mentions identification as a motive given by proponents to ban concealment, but then doesn't connect that with some comparison between those who favor banning all coverings of the face and those who only go so far as to favor banning a certain form of coverings.  Some more information, and maybe a few numbers, would be informative.

Comment: There was an instance in Florida, USA, where a woman was suing to be allowed to take her driver's license photo while having her face covered.

Comment: @jamesqf: "the daycare worker who is hardly going to memorize the face of every parent." - maybe it's different in other places, but that's exactly how it's supposed to work in Germany. The day care workers know the parents of children in their group (granted, they sometimes have photos of the parents, as well) and are trusted never to "hand over" the child to anyone else. Anyone else allowed to pick up the child is asked to have the child's parents introduce him or her first to the day care staff.

Answer (score -3):

Original answer below. First some notes on the accepted answer. It states three possible reasons:

> 1) Face coverings are perceived as an affront to feminism/women's liberation/etc...

This is fully compatible with the intro to my answer: "In a nutshell, the European reaction to everything they don't like is to try to ban it or to exterminate its practitioners" ... Europeans think Muslim women wearing the veil is an affront to feminism, so the first solution they come up with is to ban it. To the point of [sending the police to the beach to force a woman to undress](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/aug/24/french-police-make-woman-remove-burkini-on-nice-beach).

> ... There are worldwide "slut walks", whose main philosophy is feminism-based opposition

Seemingly missing the point that there is a difference between having the right to organize such protests versus dictating to others how they should dress.

> 2) It's viewed by Westerners that face coverings are symptomatic and/or symbolic of conservative/radical Islam's treatment of women.

So, the accepted answer agrees with mine that it is part of the de-Islamization drive ... similar to France's [de-Christianization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dechristianization_of_France_during_the_French_Revolution). They did not like Christian believers, so they chose to try to ban practices and exterminate practitioners.

> 3) For those who generally oppose radical Islam, this is viewed as both practical push-back (If you ban face coverings, conservative/radical Muslims wouldn't want to live in that society); as well as symbolic push-back (inasmuch as, per above point, face coverings are seen by many as a symbol of Islam).

And this is what I am warning against. First, the ban is not symbolic if people are fined for dressing a certain way, their children possibly taken away, or made to strip by police. 75 years of experience in Turkey shows even much stronger forms of repression does not dissuade the practitioners. Instead, such repression over trivial things creates becomes the rallying cry.

---

With that out of the way, here is my much down-voted answer:

This is an answer about the actual *reasons* behind these campaigns rather than the public *excuses* used to justify them.

Because there is a reason freedom-loving Europeans left Europe for America.

In a nutshell, the European reaction to [everything they don't like](https://www.algemeiner.com/2017/05/12/the-drumbeat-against-jewish-ritual-in-europe-sounds-once-more/) is to try to [ban it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_law) or to [exterminate its practitioners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dechristianization_of_France_during_the_French_Revolution):

> During a two-year period known as the Reign of Terror, the episodes of anti-clericalism grew more violent than any in modern European history. The new revolutionary authorities suppressed the church; abolished the Catholic monarchy; nationalized church property; exiled 30,000 priests and killed hundreds more. ... New forms of moral religion emerged, including the deistic ***Cult of the Supreme Being*** and atheistic ***Cult of Reason***, with the government briefly mandating observance of the former in April 1794. (emphases mine)

As [Ben Cohen observes](https://www.algemeiner.com/2017/05/12/the-drumbeat-against-jewish-ritual-in-europe-sounds-once-more/):

> American Jews are fortunate to live with a constitution clearly demarcating religion and state. European Jews don’t have such clear guidelines, and therefore become hostages to the fortunes of political clashes in which their freedom of worship is just one consideration among many.

That's why French *laïcité* is oppressive whereas American separation of church and state (that is, no government at any level has the power to regulate people's religious observances) is liberating.

The freedom not to adhere to a specific set of religious rules is vacuous if [one does not have the right](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/aug/24/french-police-make-woman-remove-burkini-on-nice-beach) to adhere to one's chosen set of religious rules:

> The images of police confronting the woman in Nice on Tuesday show at least four police officers standing over a woman who was resting on the shore ... Her ticket, seen by French news agency AFP, read that she was not wearing “an outfit respecting good morals and secularism”.

European countries would do well to learn from the experience of Turkey which banned specific forms of dress for decades (and some people [hanged for not complying with Atatürk's dress code](https://www.tbmm.gov.tr/tutanaklar/TUTANAK/TBMM/d02/c019/tbmm02019017.pdf)):

> REFİK BEY (Konya) — Bügünkü hakimiyeti milliye gazetesinin
>   neşrettiği giibi Sivas'da ve Erzurum'da şurada bura­da bazı masumlar, sırf (burada yapılan tahrik âmiz irticalkâr fikirlerin itesiriyle ızlâl edilerek ahkâmı kanuniyeye karşı hareket ederek müçrim vaziyetine düşmüşler, mahkûm olmuşlar, bunlardan bazıları idam bile edilmişlerdir. [Nurettin Paşa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nureddin_Pasha) da maksadını bu suretle istihsal etmiştir.
>
> ...
>
> Ne günahı vardır Sivas'da asılan Necati'nin, ne günahı vardır Erzurum'da asılan bir kaç masumun? Doğrudan doğruya Nurettin Pa­şa tarafından verilen takrir memleketin dört köşesine yayılmış ve efendiler görüyorsunuz ya, bu *kanun Teşkilâtı Esasiye Kanununa münafir, bu kanuni hürriyeti vicdana münafidir,* (emphasis mine)

In this snippet, Konya representative Refik Bey expresses the view that the so called *Hat Law* violates the constitution of the Republic of Turkey and violates freedom of conscience during a debate on the law to ban certain religious institutions (Full disclosure: As far as I know, my great grandfather voted for both of these laws which I have considered for a long time to be, at the very least, misguided, to the consternation of many in my family).

That was Turkey's attempt to impose the French way and change people's behavior by coercion. In late 20th century, the headscarf ban became the rallying cry of political Islam against the establishment. The consequences are now here for all to see. Clearly, even very strict bans against religious expression did little to convert supporters of such religious expression over a period of 75 years. This establishes that such bans and repression do not improve domestic security, reduce conflict between different groups. Nor do they improve women's rights. Therefore, the real motivation behind such repression must lie elsewhere.

Current attempts at banning [certain religious practices](http://www.businessinsider.com/belgium-banned-kosher-and-halal-slaughter-in-its-biggest-territory-2017-5) [are not limited to just regulating dress](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2013/oct/11/ban-male-circumcision-antisemitic), and are part and parcel of continental Europe's habit of ghettoizing people whom they consider to be beneath them.

As [Yaakov Menken points out](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Sweden-ban-Jewish-practices/answer/Yaakov-Menken):

> Given that kosher slaughter is in fact at least as humane as “stunning” via either electrocution or driving a peg into the base of an animal’s skull, to deny Jews and Muslims the ability to practice their religions, and claim it has nothing to do with bigotry, fools no one.

**Update:**

And, today, we have [another gem](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/20/world/europe/germany-36-accused-of-hateful-postings-over-social-media.html):

> “The still high incidence of punishable hate posting shows a need for police action,” Holger Münch, president of the Federal Criminal Police Office, said in a statement. “Our free society must not allow a climate of fear, threat, criminal violence and violence either on the street or on the internet.”

In the United States, despite the desire of many to institute Euro-style controls, [hate speech is still protected speech](http://www.latimes.com/opinion/op-ed/la-oe-white-first-amendment-slogans-20170608-story.html).

Comment: "Because there is a reason freedom-loving Europeans left Europe for America." The Mayflower sailed a long, long time ago...

Comment: Not the main point, but noone was hanged because of violations of dress code, that is a lie disseminated by fundamentalists using photos of Sheikh Said rebellion in order to gain sympathy. Please check your facts.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu Actually, I won't ... Reading [Konya representative Refik Bey's remarks on November 30, 1925 (page 8 of the PDF)](https://www.tbmm.gov.tr/tutanaklar/TUTANAK/TBMM/d02/c019/tbmm02019017.pdf) leaves no doubt that some people were executed for their protests against the new restrictions: *Bügünkü   hakimiyeti milliye gazetesinin neşrettiği gibi Sivas'da  ve  Erzurum'da   şurada bura­da bazı masumlar, ... mahkûm olmuşlar, bunlardan bazıları   
idam bile edilmişlerdir.*. It is instructive to read the rest of his comments.

Comment: -1 If you're going to make such significant leaps in judgment as stated in your third paragraph, you'll need significant evidence that supports the claim.

Comment: You don't need anecdotal evidence; that would be insufficient. You need to cite policy. Is there existing doctrine that empowers Europe to take the actions you've stated. Further, your fourth paragraph is wrong. There have been incidents of the US Government infringing on religious practices.

Comment: @SinanÜnür as far as I understand, those judgements were result of clashes with government forces sparking from protest, not an application of the law itself, 13 people, none from Konya. Again, it is important to note that said event is only a few months after and in same region as the Seyh Said rebellion.

Comment: How dare you attack the peaceful, progressive, and culturally sensitive people of Europe!  Its not like they have been responsible for half a dozen genocides in the last century alone!  Those are fox news lies you link too... must be.

Comment: user4012's #2 and #3 address similar reasons with much less inflammatory language.

Comment: Thus the answer continues to be of low quality, reflecting bias and making unjustified claims.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu Refik Bey specifically refers to "executed innocents". Later, İlyas Sami Bey accuses him of treason for daring to refer to those people as innocents. In his defense, Refik Bey states that these people had been provoked by [Nurettin Paşa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nureddin_Pasha): "*Açık Söylüyorum Sivas'da, Erzurum'da dökülen kan Türk kanıdır; O Türk kanının
akması doğrudan doğruya Nurettin Paşanın verdiği takrirden olmuştur, Bu itibarla o zavallıları bu kürsüden masum diyerek müdafaa etmek mecburiyetini hissettim.*" No mention of Şeyh Sait.

Comment: I feel much of this is generalised or patently false e.g. "the European reaction to everything they don't like is to try to ban it or to exterminate its practitioners" or dips into unnecessary and irrelevant topics such as the banning of kosher or circumcision. Indeed their are equivalent calls to ban circumcision in the US which overall makes your answer unreliable. Also using such phrases as "Europe's habit of ghettoizing people whom they consider to be beneath them" brings us right up to the very edge of defamy and violation of our be nice policy.

Comment: Sinan Unur, You did your research. That much is obvious and the citations are good, but by using absolute quantifiers like "everything" is this or "everything" is that, or by implying that all Europeans (including the British, the Nordic countries, and everyone else) are like Nazi Germans or like the French revolutionaries of 200+ years ago, you're starting to distort your narrative, including your own thoughts on these issues. Also, your point about French anti-religion as one of the founding principles of the French modern country is well taken. Many Americans do not understand this point.

Comment: While it's certainly true that – in general – European attitudes are somewhat different from American ones, sweeping generalisations such as "the European reaction to everything they don't like is to try to ban it or to exterminate its practitioners" show some misunderstanding of 1) the "European position" on these points, 2) that these bans are **highly** controversial in Europe, 3) fail to recognize that there are many different viewpoints.